# Unable to get result using Where condition in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, database

[image]

I am working in Database since past few years but never got struck in this type of problem. The problem is when I am firing simple query `Select * from Courses where subject_detail='Art History'` it is giving me 0 results. My data type for `subject_detail` is `nvarchar(50)` and I am using SQL server.

Answer (score 1):

I can see this not working if you have spaces at the end.

```
where trim(subject_detail)='Art History'
```

Comment: Yaps. I just checked that there is a blank space after 'Art History' in database. I removed the space and it is working correctly. SQL server does not support TRIM. It have LTRIM and RTRIM. Thank You

Comment: You are right it needs to be ltrim(rtrim(subject_detail))   - I had created a function called trim() that did this for me.